# What is the difference between import and cy.fixture in Cypress tests?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I'm learning cypress and I don't understand what differs from `import file from '../fixtures/filepath/file.json'` a fixture file and calling `cy.fixture(file)`, and when should I use each one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically when you say `import file from '../fixtures/filepath/file.json'` you can use the imported file in any of methods in the particular javascript file. Whereas if you say `cy.fixture(file.json)`, then the fixture context will remain within that cy.fixture block and you cannot access anywhere/outside of that cy.fixture block. Please go through the below code and you will understand the significance of it.

I recommend to use `import file from '../fixtures/filepath/file.json'`

For example. Run the below code to understand.

```
import fixtureFile from './../fixtures/userData.json';
describe('$ suite', () => {
  it('Filedata prints only in cy.fixture block', () => {
    cy.fixture('userData.json').then(fileData => {
      cy.log(JSON.stringify(fileData)); // You can access fileData only in this block.
    })
    cy.log(JSON.stringify(fileData)); //This says error because you are accessing out of cypress fixture context
  })

  it('This will print file data with import', () => {
    cy.log(JSON.stringify(fixtureFile));
  })

  it('This will also print file data with import', () => {
    cy.log(JSON.stringify(fixtureFile));
  })
});
```

Comment: you can use an alias. i.e: `cy.fixture('userData.json').as('userData')` to access it outside the block

Answer (score 1):

Review the documentation for `cy.fixture` - http://on.cypress.io/api/fixture

In short, using `cy.fixture` works with the asynchronous nature of Cypress, works with many encoding types and may be aliased for use throughout tests in a spec (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases)

In addition, fixtures may also be used as responses to `cy.route` - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Fixtures